# Does the Lexical Environment of a JavaScript code contain ThisBinding or does an Execution Context contain it?

Tags: javascript, this, executioncontext

My apologies if this question has been asked already, but I am a little confused about the structure of a JavaScript execution context during the creation phase. I was going through a couple of tutorials where one said that the **ThisBinding** was a component of an execution context whereas another said the same was a component of a `Lexical Environment`

- [this](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0) article here seems to say that the `this` keyword is a part of Lexical Environment structure. If true, this would mean that every Lexical Environment component created will have its `this` keyword.
- [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/javascript-basics-the-execution-context-and-the-lexical-environment-3505d4fe1be2) article here says that the `this` keyword is rather a part of the bigger execution context. If true, this would mean for every execution context created, there would exist only one `this` keyword regardless of how many Lexical Environment components it has.

Which one is correct here?

Comment: First of all I totally understand the need to understand the internal workings of something. But out of curiousity, how does this concern you?

Comment: Just to ensure that whatever I read on the internet is correct